# Selenium speed Ruby Vs Java

Tags: java, ruby, selenium

This isn't meant as a war between which is faster Java or Ruby but I've always been lead to believe that Selenium would run faster in Java compared to Ruby

[Example](https://jiaodecai.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/performance-comparison-of-selenium-java-webdriver-and-ruby-webdriver/)

[Example](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1611/1611.00578.pdf)

I've just knocked up a quick and dirty test that opens youtube does a search and loops 10 times.

Ruby out performs Java every time I run this.

I'm not using Eclipse or Rubymine just using command line.

Ruby version:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

test_start  = Time.now
for i in 1..10
beginning_time = Time.now

driver =  Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, driver_path:"C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe"
driver.navigate.to "https://www.youtube.com/"

element = driver.find_element(:id, 'masthead-search-term')
element.send_keys "Selenium"
element.submit

puts(driver.title)

driver.quit

end_time = Time.now
puts "Attempt #{i} Seconds: #{(end_time - beginning_time)}"
end

test_end  = Time.now
puts "After 10 attempts the total Seconds: #{(test_end - test_start)}"
```

Java version:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SpeedTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long testStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("https://www.youtube.com/");

            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("masthead-search-term"));
            element.sendKeys("Selenium");
            element.submit();

            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

            driver.quit(); 

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Attempt " + x + " seconds:");
            System.out.printf("%.6f%n ", (endTime - startTime)/1e3);
        }

        long testEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("Total seconds for 10 attempts: %.6f%n ", (testEnd - testStart)/1e3);
    }

}
```

Have I made a stupid mistake or is Ruby faster for this sort of testing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the language, and everything to do with how efficient it's Selenium library is. The amount of time spent "in Ruby" or "in Java" is virtually 0, all the time will be spent communicating with the browser and manipulating page elements. If you stripped out the Selenium calls, both of these code samples would basically be a few `puts` and `println` statements running so fast that they'd be basically impossible to measure.

Comment: Ok so forget about the amount of ruby or java, selenium is a java project with ruby bindings. The number of people who download the java version compared to the ruby binding is massive so why would more people use java when the library  it's about 50% slower to run selenium?

Comment: Not sure why the comments were deleted :-S I'm hosting a local page and still ruby outperforms Java

Comment: Technically java is slower cause of virtual machine which Ruby does not have, it may be difference is performance.

Comment: This really isn't a good, comprehensive comparison test since it's so simple. My guess is that if you ran each of these tests a few times, you'd get pretty different results. The time a script takes to run (assuming it's reasonably efficient) is going to be heavily affected by the browser and site speed vs the individual calls to the browser from each of the drivers. The reason more people use java over ruby likely is due to more people knowing the java language rather than execution speed.